# How to deal with nested loops when you don't know how many loops need nesting (python 3.4)?

Tags: python, for-loop

The question is framed a bit weird but to give an example, i am trying to write a program that lists all the possible alphanumerical strings given the length of the string.

so far my code is:

```
from itertools import product

alpha = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

charnum = input('How many characters\n>>>')

for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h in product(alpha, repeat = charnum):
    print(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h)
```

it is currently build assuming that the length is 8 characters however if i don't know the number i can't chose the variable names that go after the keyword 'for'.

Comment: Just use one variable `for a in product(alpha, repeat = charnum):` which will give you a tuple. Then perform the operation on that `tuple`. In this case `''.join(a)` will give you the same result.

Comment: Just a heads up that there are almost 3 trillion possible alpha strings of length 8.

Comment: Yeah i know i created this program because my brother said that an 8 length password could be easily brute-forced xD

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`''.join`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.join) and a single looping variable `seq`, like so:

```
from itertools import product

alpha = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

charnum = int(input('How many characters\n>>>'))

for seq in product(alpha, repeat = charnum):
    print(''.join(seq))
```

Comment: Thanks I also realised that i needed to put an int() around my input